# how to check whether a value exists in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, indexof

I have an array in my laravel blade file and am accessing it as below inside javascript:

```
var test = {!! json_encode($test) !!};
```

When I print the test variable in the console, it prints the variable as below:

[variable test console print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHApk.png)

I have one form input value accessed as below:

```
$("#add-employeeId").val()
```

When I print this value in the console, it prints the value as below:

[form input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXnGr.png)

Now I need to check whether the form input exists in the test variable, am doing it as below:

```
function isInArray(array, search)
    {
        return array.indexOf(search) >= 0;
    }

//check
isInArray(test, $("#add-employeeId").val())
```

But this always returns false, even the value exists. I need to know what's wrong with my check and what am missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict
> equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).

`$("#add-employeeId").val()` is returning **string** value and you are comparing it to **int** values.

Your function should be:

```
function isInArray(array, search)
{
    return array.indexOf(parseInt(search)) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Or if your array can contain decimals or strings then you should map all array elements to string

Comment: yes this was the issue, thank you for this answer

Answer (score -1):

It returns true because indexOf returns the index of the element found and -1 if it isn't found. You are asserting greather or equal to 0, which is true if the value exists. Use array.includes(search) for your use case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].includes("2")` still returns `false`

Comment: Because that is false. You have to use [1, 2, 3].includes(2)

Comment: OP is using `$("#add-employeeId").val()` which returns a string. And that is the core of the problem - mismatched types. `[1, 2, 3].includes(2)` will return the exact same result as `[1, 2, 3].indexOf(2) >= 0` And both would return `false` when searching for a string in an array of numbers.